# unable to click "sign in" on google.com with cypress scripts

Tags: cypress, ui-automation

I am trying to write a cypress script on google.com page and trying to click sign in with below code, but non of these works.

I tried with below code

```
  describe('My First Test', () => {
it('Sign In to Google.com', () => {
cy.visit('https://www.google.com')
//cy.get('iframe').focus().click('Sign In')
//cy.get('.gb_ie').click()
//cy.get('#gbqfbb').click()
//cy.get('iframe').
cy.get('.gb_ja').contains('Sign in').click()
//cy.get('.gb_ja').contains('Sign')
//cy.wait('5000')
//cy.get('.FPdoLc > center > .gNO89b')
})
})
```

but when ever I execute this, ijust runs like below and
[image]
and then automatically go to below page
[image]

It is not being on the same page, I am not sure if that is actually clicking the "Sign in" button.

can anyone suggest how to be on the same page and see the results there?

Comment: from the image you sent it looks like it opened the cypress specs tab, are you sure the code given does that without any interaction?

Comment: It should as per cypress, but I am not 100% sure why it is not clicking on sign in

Answer (score 0):

I looked into this myself and there are extra steps you need to take.

Here is the documentation for how to add google authentication to a custom command: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/end-to-end-testing/google-authentication

It is actually clicking sign in but the spec just ends. You need to set up google console and add configure cypress.env with them.

Setup google console and add your credential tokens to cypress.env

```
module.exports = defineConfig({
  env: {
    googleRefreshToken: process.env.GOOGLE_REFRESH_TOKEN,
    googleClientId: process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_CLIENTID,
    googleClientSecret: process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
  },
})
```

Create a custom custom command:

```
// cypress/support/commands.js
Cypress.Commands.add('loginByGoogleApi', () => {
cy.log('Logging in to Google')
  cy.request({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token',
    body: {
      grant_type: 'refresh_token',
      client_id: Cypress.env('googleClientId'),
      client_secret: Cypress.env('googleClientSecret'),
      refresh_token: Cypress.env('googleRefreshToken'),
    },
  }).then(({ body }) => {
    const { access_token, id_token } = body

    cy.request({
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo',
      headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${access_token}` },
    }).then(({ body }) => {
      cy.log(body)
      const userItem = {
        token: id_token,
        user: {
          googleId: body.sub,
          email: body.email,
          givenName: body.given_name,
          familyName: body.family_name,
          imageUrl: body.picture,
        },
      }

      window.localStorage.setItem('googleCypress', JSON.stringify(userItem))
      cy.visit('/')
    })
  })
})
```